# vue.js 2 nested components with inline templating results in error (component must have one child element only)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to make components that would handle some table data for me. I figured the best approach is to create a component for each part of the table.

So, I have

```
Vue.component('my-table', { ... });
Vue.component('my-table-header', { ... });
Vue.component('my-table-header-column', { ... });
```

As I was writing the code, my HTML looked like this first:

```
<my-table inline-template>
<table>
  <thead>
    ....
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ....
  </tbody>
</table>
</my-table>
```

This worked just fine.

Now I wrote the second component (my-table-header) and changed the HTML like so:

```
<my-table inline-template>
<table>
  <my-table-header inline-template>
  <thead>
    ....
  </thead>
  </my-table-header>
  <tbody>
    ....
  </tbody>
</table>
</my-table>
```

This however results in vue complaining that "Inline-template components must have exactly one child element."

I can't seem to find a good explanation on what I'm doing wrong here. It seems just by using a nested component, I create this issue.

Comment: Either your `my-table` inline component or your `my-table-header` has more than one root elements. By the flow of your work, it seems that the error occurs due to the latter. Are you sure there is no element inside `my-table-header`, same level as `thead`?

Comment: super-sure. Just re-checked (again). `<my-table-header inline-template><thead><tr><td v-for></td></tr></thead></my-table-header>`. This is all there is in there.

Comment: I'm finding that this has something to do with the `<table>` element. Changing my code to use `<div>` works.

Comment: You can try wrapping your table inside a simple `div`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was indeed with table element being finicky ands stuff getting thrown out.

I finally managed to get this working with `is="component-name"` construct, like so:

```
<my-table inline-template>
<table>
  <thead is="my-table-header" inline-template>
    <thead>....</thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    ....
  </tbody>
</table>
</my-table>
```

Ask me not why I had to repeat the thead tag. It wouldn't render without it.